# Merge Many CSV Files Leads to Kernel Death

Tags: python, csv, merge, out-of-memory, chunks

I need to preprocess a lot of **csv tables** to apply them to an autoencoder.

By using *pandas*, I read all these tables as data frames. Then I need to merge them based on a shared key(id). `merged = pd.merge(df, df1, on='id', how = 'left')`.

However, after a couple of merges the size of the resulting table became very big and killed the kernel. This is the last size I got for merging result before the kernel died `merged.shape = (29180782, 71)`. And I need to merge many more tables.

All the tables have an outlook like this but with more rows and columns (the values define in each column shows a category):

```
df:                         df1:
    id    a    b   c   d       id    e    f   g   h
0  2000   1    1   1   3      2000   1    1   1   1
1  2001   2    1   1   3      2001   2    0   0   3
2  2002   1    3   1   2      2002   1    3   1   2
3  2003   2    2   1   1      2003   1    0   1   1
```

I have tried *feather* but it doesn't help. I also did try to downcast the column types `df['a'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a'], downcast='unsigned')` but I saw no difference in table size. The last solution came up to my mind was using chunk. I tried the below code with different chunk sizes, but the kernel died again:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('df1', chunksize = 100000, low_memory=False):
    df = pd.merge(df,chunk , on='id', how = 'left')
```

So I decided to write on a file instead of using a variable to prevent the kernel from dying. At first, I saved the last merged table in a csv file in order to read from it by chunks for the next merging process.

```
lastmerged.to_csv(r'/Desktop/lastmerged.csv', index=False)
```

And then:

```
from csv import writer
for chunk in pd.read_csv('lastmerged.csv', chunksize = 100000, low_memory=False):
    newmerge = pd.merge(df1,chunk , on='id', how = 'right')

    with open('newmerge.csv', 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        for i in range (len(newmerge)):
            csv_writer.writerow(newmerge.loc[i,:])
```

I did try this piece of code on some small tables and I got the desired result. But for my real tables, it took lots of time for running and it made me to stop the kernel :| Besides, the code doesn't seem efficient!

In a nut shell, my question is how to merge tables when they got larger and larger and cause kernel's death and memory problem. 
ps. I have already tried google colab, Jupyter, and terminal. They all work the same.

Comment: When you say "a lot of csv" files can you be more precise ? Also what's the size of your files and how much lines and columns ?

Comment: Have you looked into [Dask](https://dask.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

you can collect them in a list and use

```
total_df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4...,dfn],axis = 1)
```

you can also use

```
for name in filename:
  df = pd.concat([df,pd.read_csv(name,index_col= False)])
```

So this way, you can pass the memory problem a

Comment: this will lead to same problem if the OP have a huge list of dataframes.

Comment: And it doesn't work if the indexes aren't perfectly aligned. OP therefore uses a proper merge on `id`.

Comment: if index is the problem, you can use reset_index() in the loop then add to list. If memory is the problem collect them in one df and use

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your pandas dataframes to dask dataframes. And then merge your data frames by dd.merge().

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
d_df = dd.from_pandas(df, chunksize=10000)
```

For data that fits into RAM, Pandas can often be faster and easier to use than Dask DataFrame, but when you have problem with RAM size you can use Dask to deal with hard disk and RAM.